# D3.js horizontal line chart does not show tool tip properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add tool tip for a data point which is on a horizontal line chart using D3.js. I used following code segment for it.

```js
$('svg circle').tipsy({ 
        gravity: 's',   // nw | n | ne | w | e | sw | s | se   -->  http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/
        html: true, 
        title: function(d) {
          console.log(this.__duplicateDataForLineChart__);    
          var d = this.__duplicateDataForLineChart__;
            
       //var pDateRecord = duplicateDataForLineChart[0].DateRecord;
          return d.DateRecord.toString();
        }
    });
```

But when I run the code it dose not show the tool tip, and also it shows as "**undefined**" as console statement. How can I fix this problem? (Here duplicateDataForLineChart is an array and I checked it, it has data.)

Here is the code that I used to make data points.

```js
function updateLineChart(index,subIndex){
    //svg.selectAll(".TestSuite").remove();
    
    var totalSubRoots = 0;
    for(var counter_a=0 ; counter_a<index ; counter_a++ ){
        totalSubRoots = totalSubRoots+ subRootCountHolder[counter_a];
    }
    
    totalSubRoots = totalSubRoots+subIndex;
    
    for(var counut2 = 0 ; counut2<totalSubRoots ; counut2++){
        duplicateDataForLineChart[counut2] = OriginalDataForLineChart[counut2];
    } 
    
    //alert(duplicateDataForLineChart[duplicateDataForLineChart.length-1].DateRecord);
  if (!line_dataCirclesGroup) {
  line_dataCirclesGroup = line_svg.append('svg:g');
 }

 var line_circles = line_dataCirclesGroup.selectAll('.data-point').data(duplicateDataForLineChart);
  //.data(data);

    //line_svg.selectAll(line_circles).remove();
    
 line_circles
  .enter()
   .append('svg:circle')
    .attr('class', 'data-point')
    .style('opacity', 1e-6)
                .style('stroke','#000000');
    
    line_circles
  .attr('cx', function(d) { return line_x(d.Date); })
  .attr('cy', function(d) { return line_y(d.Value); })
  .attr('r', function() { return (duplicateDataForLineChart.length <= line_maxDataPointsForDots) ? line_pointRadius : 0 })
        .style('fill', function(d){
                           if(d.TrueFalseVale == 'True'){ //"#4169E1", "#800080"
                                 
                              return "#4169E1";}
                          else{
                              return "#800080";
                               } 
                })
  .transition()
  .duration(line_transitionDuration)
  .style('opacity', 1);

 line_circles
  .exit()
   .transition()
   .duration(line_transitionDuration)
    // Leave the cx transition off. Allowing the points to fall where they lie is best.
    //.attr('cx', function(d, i) { return line_xAxis(i) })
    .attr('cy', function() { return line_y(0) })
    .style("opacity", 1e-6)
    .remove();

   $('svg circle').tipsy({ 
        gravity: 's',   // nw | n | ne | w | e | sw | s | se   -->  http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/
        html: true, 
        title: function(d) {
          console.log(d);    
          var d = this.__duplicateDataForLineChart__;
            
       //var pDateRecord = duplicateDataForLineChart[0].DateRecord;
          return d.DateRecord.toString();
        }
    });
    
   
     
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what do u see here `console.log(d)` instead of `console.log(this.__duplicateDataForLineChart__); `

Comment: it shows as undefined

Comment: @ Cyril it shows an error in return statement line as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DateRecord' of undefined" and console.log(this.__duplicateDataForLineChart__); shows as undefined

Comment: And also console.log(d) shows as undefined.

Comment: Ok,I will update my question

Comment: one last quetion what does this print `console.log(d3.select(this))` instead of `console.log(d)`

Comment: @Cyril-I typed console.log(d3.select(this)) checked... There are number of  lines which can expand as "[Array[1]]"..... I expand them all and each one has same thing. Array[1]>circle>__data__>DateRecord has the thing what I need to show in the tool tip. There is number of lines ,more than 20 print as "[Array[1]]".. what do you want to know exactly by checking this?If you can say I can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut feeling is that this is because you are selecting the data associated with the node wrong:

```
title: function(d) {
          console.log(d);    
          console.log(this.__duplicateDataForLineChart__);    


          var d = this.__duplicateDataForLineChart__;

          //var pDateRecord = duplicateDataForLineChart[0].DateRecord;
          return d.DateRecord.toString();
    }
```

Instead of that do like below:

```
   $('svg circle').tipsy({ 
        gravity: 's',   // nw | n | ne | w | e | sw | s | se   -->  http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/
        html: true, 
        title: function(d) {
          //this is how you get data from the circle
          //post discussion came to know d3.select(this).data() is an array 

          return d3.select(this).data()[0].DateRecord;  
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for answering the question, now the tool tip show, but it shows its content as "undifined"? Why is that?

Comment: do `console.log(d3.select(this).data())` inside title  `function` my applogies in making you do so many things ..frankly i am playing blind here..

Comment: then it prints 18th lines as [object] which can expand and this object has data